# Is there a way to set default values for matplotlib's colorbar?

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the default padding value of matplotlib's `colorbar`. Since I'm always setting `pad=0`, e.g.,

```
 db = colorbar(sc, ax=ax[1], pad=0)
```

it would be convenient to set this value by default, so that I don't need to add it in the colorbar's function call every single time. I haven't found any hints/solutions in the `rcParams`-related docstrings.

Is it even possible to change the default values of the colorbar (like we do in case of, e.g., `imshow` by manipulating `rcParams`)? If so, how can we do that?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: It's quite disappointing to learn that this is impossible. Thank you, though.